# Refresh SQL Database

Tags: iphone, sql

I use a SQL database in conjunction with my iPhone app. I uploaded it to the iTunes store, everything was working fine and the app was selling.  Then, I added some data to the data base and uploaded the new binary to Apple.  Apple approved the update.  Here is the problem.  When I update my app to the new version, the new records I added to the SQL database do not show.  I turned off my iPhone and restated it and they still did not show.  I then deleted the app and and reinstalled it and then the new records showed.  How do I get the app to clear the cache (my guess) and use the new SQL database?  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you've written the code but you should probably look into the option of the new app migrating the db from the old app to the new. The core data framework provides a lot of documentation on how to do it, but if you have your own SQL DB you'll need to write your own methods to migrate.

Now the specifics of how an application's environment is saved between updates on a live phone is a little over my head. I sure there is a plist evolved though!